# illegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist for chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit5

Here is the code

```
service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File("src/test/resources/driver/chromedriver.exe"))
            .usingAnyFreePort()
            .build();
```

Runtime Error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: xxxxxxx/src/test/resources/driver/chromedriver.exe
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:200)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
```

I've already check the directory for where it is searching for the chromedriver and it's there. I'm not sure what the problem is at this point. Any help would be great!

Comment: try providing full path to the file. Almost always the root cause is that the path is not set up correctly

Answer (score 0):

As you got reply from Pavel Janicek, path is the root cause so i added `System.getProperty("user.dir")`
which will return root path of your project. It might be helpful to resolve your problem.

```
service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/driver/chromedriver.exe"))
            .usingAnyFreePort()
            .build();
```